# Download hourly weatherdata : Error

Tags: r, rwunderground

Hi I am downloading hourly historical weather data from "rwunderground" package with the below code.

```
Library("rwunderground")
rwunderground::set_api_key("MY_API_KEY")
history(set_location(zip_code = "90210"), "20170101")
```

After executing the above lines the error i am getting was

```
"Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds"
```

Please help me to modify / update the above code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you facing it constantly? If it happened arbitrarily check the status through http://status.wunderground.com/ . Otherwise, increasing the timeout for the curl call may be a solution, but I do not know if you would want to wait longer than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The code worked for me fine.

If you're referencing the library, you don't need to reference it at the same time as your command: you don't need to reference `rwunderground` when using `set_api_key`. This will improve the code's layout, but it won't speed up the function.

I'll include the code and output below; at least if it doesn't work for you, you can copy it from here:

```
library(rwunderground)
set_api_key("0d5f3d47ea78fa83")
history(set_location(zip_code = "90210"), "20170101")

[1] "Requesting: http://api.wunderground.com/api/0d5f3d47ea78fa83/history_20170101/q/90210.json"
# A tibble: 24 x 21
   date                 temp dew_pt   hum wind_spd wind_gust dir     vis pressure wind_chill heat_index precip precip_rate
   <dttm>              <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 2017-01-01 00:51:00  45.0   41.0   86.     4.60        NA West    10.     29.9       42.6         NA     NA          NA
 2 2017-01-01 01:51:00  44.1   39.0   82.     4.60        NA NNE     10.     29.9       41.5         NA     NA          NA
 3 2017-01-01 02:51:00  43.0   39.9   89.     4.60        NA East    10.     29.9       40.3         NA     NA          NA
 4 2017-01-01 03:51:00  44.1   39.9   85.     3.50        NA South   10.     29.9       42.5         NA     NA          NA
 5 2017-01-01 04:51:00  43.0   39.9   89.     0.          NA North   10.     29.9       NA           NA     NA          NA
 6 2017-01-01 05:51:00  43.0   39.9   89.     0.          NA North   10.     29.9       NA           NA     NA          NA
 7 2017-01-01 06:51:00  43.0   39.9   89.     4.60        NA NNE     10.     29.9       40.3         NA     NA          NA
 8 2017-01-01 07:51:00  44.1   41.0   89.     4.60        NA NE      10.     29.9       41.5         NA     NA          NA
 9 2017-01-01 08:51:00  48.0   42.1   80.     5.80        NA NE      10.     29.9       NA           NA     NA          NA
10 2017-01-01 09:51:00  52.0   44.1   74.     5.80        NA Vari…   10.     29.9       NA           NA     NA          NA
# ... with 14 more rows, and 8 more variables: precip_total <dbl>, cond <chr>, fog <dbl>, rain <dbl>, snow <dbl>,
#   hail <dbl>, thunder <dbl>, tornado <dbl>
```

Of note, since the time it takes your computer to run the code is an issue, I thought I'd show you how long it takes for mine.

```
time <- Sys.time()
set_api_key("0d5f3d47ea78fa83")
history(set_location(zip_code = "90210"), "20170101")
Sys.time() - time
```

Time difference of 0.526396 secs

```
time <- Sys.time()
rwunderground::set_api_key("0d5f3d47ea78fa83")
history(set_location(zip_code = "90210"), "20170101")
Sys.time() - time
```

Time difference of 0.5350232 secs

Repeating above gives different but similar values - they're about the same speed.

Comment: Thanks @Mborg , i am getting same error even after removing the "rwunderground::" also i incresed timeout with curlOptions(connecttimeout = 2000)

Comment: is that error because of firewall or corporate issue..?

Comment: I think the issue lies with your internet connection @suny. It could very well be a firewall or corporate issue affecting your internet connection to `wunderground`, or that the strength of your connection wasn't good enough, but am not sure. I don't think it's a coding issue, since I had no problems using it.

Comment: Thanks @MBorg i will use my local syatem to download data..Thanks again